# Notation for b-matching definition

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, notation

I saw the following definition of a $b$-matching (here $\delta(v)$ is the set of edges incident to the vertex $v$):

> **Definition :** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and let $b\in \mathbb{Z}_+^V$. A $b$-matching is a function $x\in \mathbb{Z}_+^E$
> satisfying $$x(\delta(v))\le b(v)$$ for each $v\in V$.

But what does it mean to evaluate the function $x:E\to \mathbb{Z}_+$ on $\delta(v)$ when the latter is a set of many edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $x(\delta(v))$ is sometimes used to denote the sum $$\sum_{e \in \delta(v)} x(e).$$ This would make sense here: a $b$-matching would indicate a subgraph of $G$ whose degree at each vertex $v$ is bounded by $b(v)$.

(Technically, this definition allows for a multigraph whose simplification is a subgraph of $G$, since we can have $x(e) > 1$ for some edges $e$. Not everyone will consider that a $b$-matching.)

I also suspect that the notation is defined earlier in the text that contains this definition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The book I was looking into was combinatorial optimization by Schrijver. Strange that I could not find any mention of this.